# Jira integration with Bitbucket: sync does not work

Tags: bitbucket, jira, jira-plugin

We setup the integration of Jira Server with Bitbucket Cloud according to the [Connect Bitbucket Cloud to Jira Software Server](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/connect-bitbucket-cloud-to-jira-software-server/)
The repos were added successfully. But no futher sync performs afterwards.
We tried everything in doc [Fix error connections between Jira Cloud and Bitbucket](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/fix-error-connections-between-jira-cloud-and-bitbucket/) and these did not help.
The sync state is hanging forever: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhq2T.png)

The clicking on sync button does not work (either by hands or automatically).

This issue looks like a bug since there are no ERROR or WARN messages in atlassian-jira.log file concerning this issue (we switched the following log appenders into DEBUG level: com.atlassian.jira.plugins.dvcs, com.atlassian.jira.plugins.dvcs.scheduler, com.atlassian.jira.plugins.dvcs.spi.bitbucket, com.atlassian.jira.plugins.dvcs.spi.bitbucket.BitbucketCommunicator).

So it looks like the sync works ok but it does not.

How can we fix the sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved (partially I suppose) by restarting Jira server.
The possible reason is in leaking http connection in Apache HttpClient.